# BlueOceanCredentialsProvider Issue

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, ldap, jenkins-blueocean

I had installed BlueOceanCredentials plugin in jenkins. However, after Jenkins start up the logs are flooding with the below error:

> WARNING    i.j.b.r.i.p.c.BlueOceanCredentialsProvider#getCredentials: BlueOceanCredentialsProvider#getCredentials(): Username attached to credentials can not be found

I couldn't find whether this issue is due to issue with the plugin or with the Jenknins jobs which tries to checkout the GIT repo has any reference to the LDAP user in the code base.

There's in related ticket: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-53188

In fact, my jenkins server is facing 'Too many Files' issue - I strongly suspect that it is due to the above warning which is flooding the logs.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue - This is because of the user which were deleted in the LDAP are still available under /users/users.xml
After removing the deleted users entry from the XML, the warnings are no more appearing in the logs.

Thanks for who attempted!